# Sprint Boot in a multi-module project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In our team we're having a bit of a discussion while developing a fairly straightforward Spring Boot app. Because we wanted to clearly separate concerns, we have modularized (Maven modules) our system into three modules:

- *Service*: has the Spring Boot dependency, depends on *Model* & *Repository*
- *Model*: only has the domain classes and 'service' classes (**no** Spring Boot dependency)
- *Repository*: only has the JDBC access logic (depends on *Model*, **no** Spring Boot dependency)

I've done a few Spring Boot projects before and this is the first time I've set it up like this. I have particular concerns as to whether it makes sense to keep Spring Boot out of Repository because it will require us to do a lot of the wiring, like JDBC, jooq, liquibase, etc. manually in Service.

Has anyone got any advice about whether or not it makes sense to do it like this?

Comment: what do you mean by `(no Spring Boot dependency)`?

Comment: I mean there is no dependency in the Repository module to any Spring Boot library, only directly to postgres/jooq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this question might have opinion based answers. However... I think that this separation can lead to a development model that looks more like the old waterfall model rather than modern approaches. As microservices approaches teach, I think that it could be better to apply a vertical separation of concerns, modularizing the application in functional areas and not by abstraction level. Internally, each module should handle everything is related to its functional area.

> I have particular concerns as to whether it makes sense to keep Spring Boot out of Repository because it will require us to do a lot of the wiring, like JDBC, jooq, liquibase, etc. manually in Service.

If you use correctly TDD frameworks this should not be an issue. I already work on multi-module Maven projects (Spring Boot) and I have never had issues about this, but obviously it depends on what you are doing in your projects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have an issue understanding the last paragraph. What I meant to say was that the injection, which is normally taken care of by Spring, will have to be done manually in code, in the Service project, because it cannot rely on annotations, component-scanning, since there is no Spring dependency in Repository. I don't understand why you bring up TDD here, I guess because there is a similar wiring-challenge there?

Comment: Yes, there is some wiring challenge. Setting up correctly parent `pom.xml` will allow you to have the injection in all your submodules. One warning: this can be easy or difficult depending on what you have to do in your project. It is very difficult to give a more precise answer at this level of abstraction.